# android retrofit unable to parse data geting null

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have json data which I'm parsing using gson converter and giving response to pojo class and displaying it. I am getting null. I've seen many question regarding this but I din't get much solution. See what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to retrofit.

```
{
  "loginj": [
    {
      "JUser_Id": "20",
      "JFullName": "aaa",
      "JEmail": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

see my retrofit builder class

```
 public static APIInterface getInterfaceService() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    final APIInterface mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
    return mInterfaceService;
}
```

model class

```
public class Loginj {
   private String JUser_Id;
   private String JFullName;
   private String JEmail;
}
```

callback class APIInterface

```
Call<Loginj> login(@Body User user);
```

getting response

```
Call<Loginj> loginResponseCall = apiInterface.login(user);
loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Loginj> () {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<Loginj>  call, Response<Loginj>   response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                   Loginj bodywValue = response.body();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+bodywValue.getJFullName(),
                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<Loginj>  call, Throwable t){}
```

Comment: What is Loginj here?

Comment: loginj model class  there all fielads are thare

Comment: And you are getting Loginj null right?

Comment: See my answer, I will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Here your response is in array you need to change like this

```
{
  "JUser_Id":"20",
 "JFullName":"aaa",
 "JEmail":"abc@gmail.com"
}
```

**Option 2:**

If you can't change your API response then, create pojo for a response that matches your response JSON.

```
public class RestResponse {
 public List<Loginj> loginj;
}
```

THen your code should look like this

```
Call<RestResponse> loginResponseCall = apiInterface.login(user);
            loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<RestResponse> () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RestResponse>  call, Response<RestResponse>   response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        RestResponse body = response.body();
                        Loginj bodywValue = body.loginj.get(0);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+bodywValue.getJFullName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }}

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure
                    (Call<RestResponse>  call, Throwable t){

                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you `json` example is right, then `loginj` is an array of objects, but you're saying to retrofit, that you want a single object.

Try something like this:

```
public class Loginj {

    private List<LoginjData> loginj;

    private class LoginjData {
        private String JUser_Id;
        private String JFullName;
        private String JEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its working  i can accept this but some other answer is more clear  i up voted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Make one more Model class.

```
public class ANY_NAME{
  private List<Loginj> loginj;
 }
```

and replace this code:

```
Call<Loginj> login(@Body User user);
```

With this:

```
 Call<ANY_NAME> login(@Body User user);
```

Your code will work